# Spring Security not sending CSRF token in REST Application

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, csrf

I'm new to Spring Security and I'm trying to understand the CSRF mechanism. I have a Spring based application with Angular. As far as I know, Spring will send a CSRF Token in a cookie on the first GET Request it recieves (called XSRF-TOKEN) and then on every subsequent request it will look for that token in another cookie called (X-XSRF-TOKEN). My problem is that it doesn't generate a token and I can't figure out why. I'm using the latest Spring and Angular versions.

[Link to the github repo](https://github.com/rborisovv/Cors-Demo)

I created a dummy application, in which I have a /home endpoint, which accepts GET request and then returns a dummy string. I've set the withCredentials: true on the Angular side and I've configured CookieCsrfTokenRepository. I don't see the Set-cookie header containing the token. What am I expected to do and what am I doing wrong?

Spring Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations())
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/home")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Request-With", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "XSRF-TOKEN", "X-XSRF-TOKEN"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "XSRF-TOKEN", "X-XSRF-TOKEN"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                HttpMethod.PUT.name(), HttpMethod.PATCH.name(),
                HttpMethod.DELETE.name(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name()
        ));
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }
}
```

Home Controller

```
@RestController
public class HomeResource {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "Home is working";
    }
}
```

Angular

home.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeService {

  apiHost: string = 'http://www.localhost:8000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  public home(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiHost}/home`, {withCredentials: true, responseType: 'text'});
  }
}
```

home.component.html

```
<p>{{home$ | async}}</p>
```

home.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  home$!: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private homeService: HomeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.home$ = this.homeService.home();
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help you https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework

Comment: What is your version of Spring Boot, Spring Security, Spring Framework?

Comment: My Spring Boot version is 3.0.0, my Spring version is 6.0.2 and my Spring Security version is 6.0.0

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Does that mean that spring security won't automatically generate a token anymore and I have to do it myself? Because I added the code from the docs and still can't see any token being generated. The only thing I see is that a CSRF token supplier is added as attribute to the request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please refer to this [Migration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_defer_loading_csrftoken), and read it completely.

In summary, Spring Security 6.0 defer the loading of the `CsrfToken`, this means that it will not include the token automatically in the response.

You have a few ways to solve this:

1. Restore the old behavior (as described in the documentation):

```java
@Bean
DefaultSecurityFilterChain springSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    // set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
    requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);
    http
        // ...
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

2. Create a controller endpoint that retrieves the `CsrfToken` from the request:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/csrf")
public class CsrfController {

    @GetMapping
    public void getCsrfToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12094#issuecomment-1294150717
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        csrfToken.getToken();
    }

}
```

You might consider `http.requestMatchers("/csrf").permitAll()`.

In all cases, you have simply to access the CsrfToken from request attributes.

And, on the Angular side, you can create a `APP_INITIALIZER` provider that will get the CSRF token when the application initializes:

```js
function getCsrfToken(httpClient: HttpClient): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => httpClient.get('/csrf').pipe(catchError((err) => of(null)));
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: getCsrfToken,
      deps: [HttpClient],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: According to the doc this method will only work if you configured CSRF protection with `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository`. You need session management for that.